# Test failing in locally built firefox

Tags: javascript, testing, mozilla, xpcshell

I have just built mozilla from the source code. I then performed the xpcshell-test and some tests are failing. These are tests that failed :-

```
dom/push/test/xpcshell/test_register_success_http2.js
-----------------------------------------------------
FAIL [Parent]
dom/push/test/xpcshell/test_register_error_http2.js
---------------------------------------------------
FAIL [Parent]
dom/push/test/xpcshell/test_unregister_success_http2.js
-------------------------------------------------------
FAIL [Parent]
dom/push/test/xpcshell/test_notification_http2.js
-------------------------------------------------
FAIL [Parent]
dom/push/test/xpcshell/test_registration_success_http2.js
---------------------------------------------------------
FAIL [Parent]
netwerk/test/unit/test_immutable.js
-----------------------------------
FAIL [Parent]
netwerk/test/unit/test_origin.js
--------------------------------
FAIL [Parent]
netwerk/test/unit/test_protocolproxyservice.js
----------------------------------------------
FAIL [Parent]
netwerk/test/unit/test_socks.js
-------------------------------
FAIL [Parent]
netwerk/test/unit/test_http2.js
-------------------------------
FAIL [Parent]
netwerk/test/unit/test_altsvc.js
--------------------------------
FAIL [Parent]
netwerk/test/unit/test_unix_domain.js
-------------------------------------
FAIL [Parent]
```

I just want to start contributing to mozilla development. Do I have to worry about this ?

Comment: You should start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Introduction

Answer (score 0):

Tests **should not** fail. However, depending on how a build was performed (e.g. tweaking the configuration in `.mozconfig`) some tests *may* fail. Moreover, there's a class of tests that can fail intermittently.

In general, if the test was passing before you made some changes, then you need to worry, as you introduced a regression in the code. If the tests are failing without you performing any change, then it's worth filing a bug in the appropriate component on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org): developers will figure out why that's failing and eventually fix the problem.